# Navigator​.mediadevices.get​User​Media() not accessing the laptops inbuilt camera

Tags: javascript, webrtc, recordrtc

I am developing a web application for video recording.

I have tried the below code but the problem is it working fine with a external  camera, but in the laptops inbuilt camera with the same Browser it is giving no Object found error.

I am using Firefox 60.6.1

```
     if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {       
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(stream) {
    //load the stream in the video variable
        video.srcObject = stream;
    //load the stream in revokeAccess variable 
        revokeAccess=stream;
    //video playback
        video.play(); 
    /*
    Optional to avoid the dual audio disturbance. Playback audio is muted
    */
    video.muted= true;


    if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
      var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
      console.log("using vp9");
    } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=h264')) {
      var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};
      console.log("using h264");
    } else  if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
      var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8',videoBitsPerSecond : 1500000,audioBitsPerSecond : 160000};
      console.log("using vp8");
    }else{
    console.log('isTypeSupported is not supported, using default codecs for browser');
    } 

    //load the stream and type of video in the function
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,options);
    //handle the data availability
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    //Start the recording
    mediaRecorder.start(); 

    alert("Started Recording");


    //push the data into chunks(array)
    function handleDataAvailable(event) {
     if (event.data.size > 0) {
       recordedChunks.push(event.data);
        console.log(recordedChunks);
     } else {
      alert(event);
     }
    }
    //disable the Start Recording button
    document.getElementById("startRecording").disabled = true;  
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
    //handle the device not found exception
        alert("Camera not Found !! Please connect camera properly");
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

I want the application to be working in each platform.

Comment: Do you mean `NotFoundError`? That would suggest the camera is not working, or a driver issue. Does the camera work in other browsers or applications? What model is this?

Comment: It is going in else loop without asking for the permission. Camera is working when I open the camera from windows camera option

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? What model is it?

Comment: It works on desktop Firefox 60.6.1  with external camera but it is not working in Laptop Firefox 60.6.1 with in built camera

Comment: If you can't answer my questions, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All Developers Thanks for your support and quick response.

I fixed the issues using the below adapter addition in the code.

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support legacy browser, check following.

https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter

> WebRTC adapter
>
> adapter.js is a shim to insulate apps from spec changes and prefix
>   differences. In fact, the standards and protocols used for WebRTC
>   implementations are highly stable, and there are only a few prefixed
>   names. For full interop information, see webrtc.org/web-apis/interop.
>
> This repository used to be part of the WebRTC organisation on github
>   but moved. We aim to keep the old repository updated with new
>   releases.

Also, you can check your hardware environment form firefox.

In the address bar on browser type following

> about:support